# Moment.js (Relative time)

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm building a social network app using react.js, I'm using moment.js to get relative time when a user add a post it should be on that behavior : a few seconds ago 1 minute ago 2 minutes ago and so on ......but it keep displayong a few seconds ago even if the post was created two days ago

`<span className="date">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</span>`

`import moment from 'moment';

export const addPost = (req, res) => {
const token = req.cookies.accessToken;

```
if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json("Not logged in!");
}

jwt.verify(token, "secretkey", (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(403).json("Token not valid");
    }

    const q = "INSERT INTO posts (`desc`, `img`, `createdAt`, `userId`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    const values = [
        req.body.desc,
        req.body.img,
        moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
        userInfo.id
    ];

    db.query(q, values, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json("Post created");
    });
});
```

};
`

Comment: If you're building something new, I wouldn't suggest using Moment. [Moment's docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) say: "We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode."

Comment: @tabet, could you tell us what value does `post.createdAt` have.  Can you give us set of sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: = the moment when the user add a new post

Answer (score 0):

Try using formatRelative form date-fns like :

```
import { format, formatRelative } from 'date-fns';
const result = formatRelative(post.createdAt, new Date());
```

check that all dates you provide are from different time in the past like

```
console.log(format(post.createdAt));
```

when creating posts use

```
const values = [
        req.body.desc,
        req.body.img,
        format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        ...
    ];
```